# What does %d mean in struct.pack?

Tags: python, struct

I was reading though a library of python code, and I'm stumped by this statement:

```
struct.pack( "<ii%ds"%len(value), ParameterTypes.String, len(value), value.encode("UTF8") )
```

I understand everything but`%d`, and I'm not sure why the length of `value` is being packed in twice.

As I understand it, the structure will have little endian encoding (`<`) and will contain two integers (`ii`) followed by %d, followed by a string (`s`).

What is the significance of `%d`?

Comment: The statement is inherently **BUGGY*. See my answer. Which library?-)

Comment: It's a library of functions written where I work, for dealing with messages sent over a network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an ordinary [string format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) which is being used to create the struct format

Try reading it to begin with as an ordinary string (forget `struct` for the moment) ...

```
"<ii%ds" % len(value)
```

If, for example, the length of the value iterable is 4 then the string will be, `<ii4s`. This is then passed to `struct.pack` ready to pack two integers followed by a string of length four bytes from the `value` iterable

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with python, so I didn't realise that you can format strings like that.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: Please find a tutorial.

Comment: @Brendan: Not OK; it's NOT any old iterable, it's a unicode string, and "4 strings from the value iterable" is nonsense when the struct.pack "4s" format is expecting 4 **bytes**

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realise that the string modifier was for the number of bytes in the string, not the number of strings - I have only used `struct` with floats and ints.

Answer (score 2):

Aarrrgh the mind boggles ....

@S.Lott: """I don't think the number is particularly important, since Python will tend to pack correctly without it.""" **-1**.  Don't think; investigate. Without a number means merely that the number defaults to 1. Tends to pack correctly??? Perhaps you think that `struct.pack("s", foo)` works the same way as `"%s" % foo`? It doesn't; [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters) say """*For the 's' format character, the count is interpreted as the size of the string, not a repeat count like for the other format characters; for example, '10s' means a single 10-byte string, while '10c' means 10 characters. For packing, the string is truncated or padded with null bytes as appropriate to make it fit.*"""

@Brendan: **-1**. `value` is not an array (whatever that is); it is patently obviously intended to be a unicode string ... lookee here: `value.encode("UTF8")`

@Matt Ellen: **The line of code that you quote is severely broken. If there are any non-ASCII characters in `value`, data will be lost.**

Let's break it down:

```
`struct.pack("<ii%ds"%len(value), ParameterTypes.String, len(value), value.encode("UTF8"))`
```

Reduce problem space by removing the first item

`struct.pack("<i%ds"%len(value), len(value), value.encode("UTF8"))`

Now let's suppose that `value` is `u'\xff\xff'`, so `len(value)` is 2.

Let `v8` = `value.encode('UTF8')` i.e. `'\xc3\xbf\xc3\xbf'`.

Note that `len(v8)` is 4. Is the penny dropping yet?

So what we now have is

`struct.pack("<i2s", 2, v8)`

The number 2 is packed as 4 bytes, `02 00 00 00`. The 4-byte string `v8` is TRUNCATED (by the length 2 in "2s") to length two. DATA LOSS. FAIL.

The correct way to do what is presumably wanted is:

```
v8 = value.encode('UTF8')
struct.pack("<ii%ds" % len(v8), ParameterTypes.String, len(v8), v8)
```

Comment: Thanks John. This is very informative. I'll pass it onto the person who wrote the library. (My boss, *gulp*)

Answer (score 1):

The significance of `%d` is that it's a formatting parameter for strings:
[String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

When broken apart, `"<ii%ds" % len(value)` is a bit easier to understand. It is replacing the %d conversion indicator in the string with the return value of `len(value)`, typecast appropriately.

```
>>> str = "<ii%ds"
>>> str % 5
'<ii5s'
>>> str % 3
'<ii3s'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` means this works in two steps.

Step 1.

```
"<ii%ds"%len(value)
```

Creates the struct formatting string of `"<ii...some number...s"`.

Step 2.

The resulting formatting string is applied to three values

```
ParameterTypes.String, len(value), value.encode("UTF8")
```

Comment: -1. Don't think; investigate. Without a number means merely that the number defaults to 1. Tends to pack correctly??? Perhaps you think that struct.pack("s", foo) works the same way as "%s" % foo? It doesn't; docs say """For the 's' format character, the count is interpreted as the size of the string, not a repeat count like for the other format characters; for example, '10s' means a single 10-byte string, while '10c' means 10 characters. For packing, the string is truncated or padded with null bytes as appropriate to make it fit."""

Comment: @John Machin: Since I revised my answer, I'm not sure any of this is still relevant.  But thanks for pointing out my egregious error.

Answer (score 0):

It's used to specify that a string (`value`) of `len(value)` characters is to be packed after those two integers.

If, for instance, `value` contained `"boo"` then the actual format specifier for `pack` would be `"<ii3s"`.